# Android Tablet (stuck in loop?)

Tags: tablet

I need to know if there is any way to backup files before I reboot my tablet. It has frozen on startup.

Nextbook 7P12

Stuck in infinite loop during startup.

Was getting to the third load screen (the flower)

Now, it rests on the second load screen (girl with headphones)

Pretty certain I'm going to be told there is no way to save my files, it's too late. I'm here to know and then move on to fixing it so it can, in the least, be usable again.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You could always try to boot the tablet into the bootloader and pull off the info via adb. Just search on google for how to put your tablet into bootloader mode then look up the commands for adb and then you can pull off the info. The other option if you can get adb access, is to install a custom recovery. Then you can pull off the recovery files and go through them like that. Most recovery backup options put them in a compressed archive files.

Comment: To install a custom recovery, you need to unlock the bootloader, and that will wipe all the data.

Comment: adb only works if you can boot into at least recovery mode. You even need to be able to boot into at least recovery mode to use fastboot also. If you can't boot at all, neither fastboot or adb will recognize the device. To try and boot to a recovery menu on this device, you try to boot by holding down the power button and the vol down button.